# gnuplot: customize labels on bar plots

Tags: gnuplot

The following script make a bar graphs indicating the y values directly on the colored bars.

```
set term pngcairo size 1200,900
set title "$file_name" noenhanced font "Century,28" textcolor "#b8860b"
set xtics noenhanced font "Helvetica,10"
set xlabel "Residue, #"
set ylabel "dG, kKal/mol"
set yrange [-10:0]
set ytics 1.0
set grid y
set key off
set boxwidth 0.9
set style fill solid 0.5
plot \$data using 0:2:3:xtic(1) with boxes lc rgb var, \
        '' using 0:2:2 with labels offset 0,1
```

how could I additionally modify the text size and its color of the values corresponded to the Y-values in each bar ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you consulted `help labels`?

For example something like this:

```
set samples 11
plot '+' u 1:1 w boxes, '+' u 1:1:1 w labels tc "red" font ",14"
```

Not much different in your example:

```
plot \$data using 0:2:3:xtic(1) with boxes lc rgb var, \
        '' using 0:2:2 with labels tc "red" font "Arial Bold,14" offset 0,1  
  # or whatever font you have available
```

Comment: may you please show it in the context of my example considering plot \$data using 0:2:3:xtic(1) with boxes lc rgb var, \
        '' using 0:2:2 with labels offset 0,1

Comment: great thank you! and how to make the font BOLD ? ;-)